# How to reduce Disk Space on SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that uses much more disk space than is actually needed.  It has reserved 171 GB but the data is only 1.9 GB. (the database was created a long time ago by someone else).
SQL Server Version: 12.0.5659.1 (which I guess is SQL Server 2014)

[Disk Usage Report Before Shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH7b0.png)

I want to get it down to a reasonable size like 2 or 3 GB.

I ran DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'XXXHelper_data', 4000, TRUNCATEONLY)
but it only got rid of about 80 GB.
[Disk Usage Report After Shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae8T8.png)

I read somewhere that a DB cannot be shrunk to smaller than the size that was originally declared when the DB was created. (but don't know if that's true)

I have done some research and found that there may be several possible techniques to accomplish this (some of which could fragment indexes, etc.). I need some help picking the best one.

TIA

Comment: This should be deleted. The OP posted their question both on SO and this site which renders this migrated version a duplicate.